# Developing a simple file browsing web app in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to develop an ASP.NET Core web app to list the files in a directory on the server with the below interactions:

1. Files are listed as hyperlinks so that when they are clicked, the file is download.
2. Folders in the directory are hyperlinks to step into that folder and then again display all files and folders in that directory
3. If there is an .html file in that directory, that html page is displayed instead of listing all the files and folders. It can be assumed that there will only ever be at most one html file in a given directory.

I have gotten (1) to work. But I don't know how to do the other two.

It does not need to look fancy at all. I essentially want it to look just like it does when typing a directory into a browser (e.g. file:///C:/) but the difference being that it is displaying files on a remote server and that it displays any html file in that directory.

I'm assuming this is a really easy task and that there is probably a prebuilt solution out there that I am just not aware of (I am extremely new to web development). My thought for achieving (2) was to have a single Index.cshtml page and just take the text after the web address as a string parameter and turn that into a directory path. e.g. https://localhost:8080/windows would display the files and folders in c:\windows. This kind of worked, but only the first time the user types in an address. If they try and go a folder deeper then it doesn't. And I think it is because it is no longer on the index page? I am guessing this whole approach is wrong.

Comment: In IIS server there was a setting that does most of what you want. Aer you using IIS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/directorybrowse

Comment: If you've got the file listed as a hpyerlink, what happens right now when you click that hyperlink?

Comment: Firstly, you should consider the security issue, while hosting the application, it will need the admin permission for your application to query the directory. Then I suggest you could consider writing a specific action method to query current path and return it to the client-side. Something like let the client passed C/test and then you should query the C/TEST to and show the directoy and file to the view page.

Comment: @Nick.Mic for developing I've been using Kestral instead of IIS Express. I did see that in the Program.cs I can add 'app.UseDirectoryBrowser' and that does what I am looking for from a browsing standpoint but doesn't download the file when clicking on it, and it doesn't display the html page if there is a file ending in the .html extension. Does IIS do those things?

Comment: @BrandoZhang in regards to security, this webpage would be sitting behind a vpn and the root browsing directory would not be the c-drive. I Just wrote it like that for simplicity. In reality the root directory would be some other folder that is dedicated to displaying the files that I wish to display.

Would the query be pulled from the address that the user types in or are you suggesting to have an input field in a form? I would need it to be pulled from the address.

Comment: Something like the path passed from client to the server, then server query the path and return the file name and directory to  the backend.